# Render being cropped

Tags: rendering

When I render, it crops the image.[image: cropped render]

Comment: I suspect it just hasn’t finished the render, and it’s working on the first tile. Have you set your sample count very high or turned “square samples” on?

Answer (score 1):

Check if render region is off:

[image]